# React useEffect upon adding a dependacy array nothing renders and funtion doesnt work

Tags: reactjs

This code works fine with finally preventing memory leak warning, however when I use fetchingPokemons in the depandancy array nothing renders on the screen. I would like to use it in dependancy array because I believe Its good practice to fill the dependancy array.

```
const usePokemons = (): IusePokemons => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<IPokemon[]>();
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  const fetchingPokemons = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(urls.pokemonDataUrl, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(await json.results);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetchingPokemons();
      return () => {
        abortController.abort();
      };
    },
    //if I put fetchingPokemons inside dependancy array
    //then fetched pokemons dont show up on screen why is that?
    [fetchingPokemons],
  );
  return {data, error, isLoading};
};

export default usePokemons;
```

Comment: Please post the code that is not working. A working code doesn't help to debug. Why do you want to put `fetchingPokemons` to the dependency array? Does the ESLINT tell you so?

Comment: Ok no problem ill write fetchingPokemons in depandancy array and thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not always need to fill the dependency array with something, but only variables on which the effect depends.

The issue in your case is that `fetchingPokemons` is redefined each time the component renders, which keeps triggering the effect.

In order to avoid that problem, you can wrap the `fetchingPokemons` function using the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook, which would memoize it and ensures that you have a single instance, thus not triggering the effect on every render:

```
  const fetchingPokemons = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(urls.pokemonDataUrl, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(await json.results);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: so then I can use  fetchingPokemons in depandacy array? Otherwise if I cant, this code is same as mine

Comment: Yes, by memorizing the function, you can have it as a dependency as it will only trigger the effect once.

Comment: what do you think causes fetchingPokemons to change? that confuses me, because it simply is fetching some 20 pokemons and thats it, what causes it to change or as u say redefine?

Comment: I'll try to explain it in simple words: During your component initial render, all of the code in that component executes (including the definition of `fetchingPokemons` function), after the mount, the `useEffect` content is executed and causes to component to re-render, which results in re-executing the whole content of the component (including the definition of `fetchingPokemons` function, once again). So on every render, you have a new instance of that function, the `useCallback` hook helps memoizing it, which means that on every render, you get the same instance (which is the initial one).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fill the dependency array every time. An empty dependency array makes sure that the `useEffect` will run on the initial render. If you are not using any state variable or prop inside the `useEffect`, you don't need to fill out the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => fetchSomething(), []) //Will run once
useEffect(() => fetchSomething(props.id), [props.id]) //Will run every time props.id changes
```

In the second example, it makes much sense you would want to execute `fetchSomething` everytime `props.id` changes.

#### Example

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React

const App = () => {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("runs once")
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("rouns every time counter changes", counter)
  }, [counter])
  
  return <button onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)}> Click me </button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'))
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

dependency array is ment to run when the value of the variable changes(just like a watcher)... well i dont see a reason why you should add a function to the dependency array...

what i will suggest is that...

1. if you want the useEffect function to be triggered when a certain data attribute in your app changes then input the value there instead of the fetchingPokemons
2. Else if you want the useEffect function to run once then leave the array empty

Comment: Please explain the 1. to me, like write me an example please, it might be very useful to me

Answer (score -1):

The dependency array should be filled only with state variables created via `React.useState()`, because they force the `uesEffect` to run when the state changes. You can choose only from your state variables, that is: `isLoading`, `data` and `error` to handle their change. Putting your custom arrow function there is not going to work under any circumstances.